# Solving $\frac {e^x-3}{e^x-2}-|x|=0$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, fractions

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

$$\frac {e^x-3}{e^x-2}-|x|=0$$

I have tried to solve it by algebric mode, but I got stuck at this point:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x \ge0 \\  
x(2-e^x)=3-e^x
\end{array}
\right. \cup 
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x <0 \\  
x(e^x-2)=3-e^x
\end{array}
\right.;\ x\neq\log(2) $$

Someone could give me a hint for solve it?

If I would want to solve it by graphic mode, how should I proceed?

Comment: This formula is transcendental and must be solved by graphing. Any function grapher will work. Mathematical software, such as Mathematica, will immediately give you a result.

Comment: @Cocomos, I'm sorry but this equation is supposed to be solved with just a pen and a piece of paper, during an exam.

Comment: In that case, try to find the critical points or study the behavior using $f'(x)$ where $f$ is the function defined by your equation and plug each one into the formula to see which one gives you the answer. Do this for $x<0$ and $x\geq0$. You will find there is only one root and it is in the region $x<0$.

Comment: @Cocomos, How should I find the critical points? With just the domine I see that $x\neq\log(2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: The]

Let $$f(x) = \frac{\exp(x)-3}{\exp(x)-2}-|x|=1-\frac{1}{\exp(x)-2}-|x|$$

If $x <0$, $$ f(x) = 1-\frac{1}{\exp(x)-2}+x$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{\exp(x)}{(\exp(x)-2)^2}+1$$

Hence it is increasing.

You might like to examine $f(0)$ and $f(-2)$ and conclude that there is a unique solution in $(-2,0)$.

If $x \geq 0$,$$ f(x) = 1-\frac{1}{\exp(x)-2}-x$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{\exp(x)}{(\exp(x)-2)^2}-1$$

Find the asymptote and prove that it doesn't go close to $0$.

Comment: How did you choose the points to examine?

Comment: Once I have proven that it is increasing. it is natural to pick $f(0)$ and see that $f(0) > 0$ after which, I can try $f(-1)$ and see if it is positive or negative, in this case, we see that $f(-1)$ is positive.  Now let me try $f(-2)$, it's negative. Hence a root must exists between $-2$ and $-1$. You can use binary search to look for the root.

Comment: Note that you still have to prove there is no positive solution, of which heropop has provided an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x) = \frac{e^x - 3}{e^x - 2} = \frac{e^x - 2 - 1}{e^x - 2} = 1 - \frac{1}{e^x-2}, \\ g(x) = |x|.$$  Then we seek the intersection of $f$ and $g$.  Note $f$ contains a singularity when $e^x = 2$, or $x = \log 2$.  We see also that $f < 0$ when $\log 2 < x < \log 3$, and since $\log 3 > 1$, it follows that $f < g$ when $x > \log 2$, and no solutions exist on this interval.

When $0 \le x < \log 2$, it is easy to see $f > g$, so again, no solutions here, and we can now restrict our attention to the case where $x < 0$, hence $g(x) = -x$, and now we seek the solution to $$(e^x - 2)(1+x) = 1.$$  This has no closed form solution.  Numeric approximation using Newton's method is possible; e.g., consider $$x_{n+1} = \frac{e^{x_n}(x_n^2+x_n-1)+3}{e^{x_n}(x_n+2)-2},$$ for some suitable initial guess $x_0 < 0$.  Convergence is rapid; we get $$x \approx -1.558781663973784196536245468626.$$

Comment: Would be easier to find the interval in which the solution is contained? If so, how should I proceed?